# WPF Main Window is always above other windows

Tags: c#, wpf, events, window

There is much of code. But problem is there:
I've got a Listbox with Control as DataTemplate:

```
<ListBox x:Name="UpcomingConcertsList" ItemsSource="{Binding UpcomingConcerts}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" Margin="10,208,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Control MouseDoubleClick="UpcomingConcert_DoubleClick">
                    <Control.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" CornerRadius="4" Width="320">
                                <Grid Margin="3">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="100" Height="75" Margin="6" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,6">
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:g}}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bands, Converter={StaticResource BandsConverter}}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Control.Template>
                </Control>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And click event code behind:

```
private void Concert_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        Concert concert = control.DataContext as Concert;

        ConcertView wndw = new ConcertView(concert.ConcertID);

        wndw.Show();
    }
```

And ConcertView window is opened but just under my MainWindow. wndw.Activate(), wndw.Focus() don't help.
I tried to do this.IsEnabled = false and wndw.Show() after this. Then my ConcertView was above MainWindow. But as this.IsEnabled comes to true, ConcertView suddenly goes under.

Is ther eany ideas?

Comment: Did you try `wndw.TopMost = true;` ??

Comment: @vishakh369 Yes I tried. Of course, my wndw gets above all the windows. But TopMost makes my window being over all the applications. But I just need my ConcertVIew to appear above MainWindow. I also tried wndw.TopMost = true and wndw.TopMost = false after Thread.Sleep(x) (Sleep is just to check if it works correct) - so my wndw got top and after that got under MainWindow

Comment: I am posting my reply as answer since it's too long and contains code. Anyways I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**But TopMost makes my window being over all the applications** What do you mean by this? You're currently using an application and when you click a button, a new window is loaded. So you want the new window to be at topmost itself right?

You can set the **Owner** property of a window to set it's owner. ie the **MainWindow**. If you set **this** then the current window will be owner window.

```
Window ownedWindow = new Window();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Show();
```

Now try setting the `wndw.TopMost = true;`and check if its working.